# Change async/await to Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, supertest

I would like to change the following async/await code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const supertest = require('supertest')
const app = require('../app')

const api = supertest(app)

test("total number of blogs", async () => {
  const response = await api.get('/api/blogs')
  
  expect(response.body).toHaveLength(1)
})
      

afterAll(() => {
  mongoose.connection.close()
})
```

to a Promise like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const supertest = require('supertest')
const app = require('../app')

const api = supertest(app)

test("total number of blogs", () => {
  api.get('/api/blogs')
    .then( response => {
      expect(response.body).toHaveLength(1)
    })
})


afterAll(() => {
  mongoose.connection.close()
})
```

I could not manage to solve it correctly and I keep getting an error message:
[image]

Comment: You need to return the promise chain.

Comment: you can check in the docs https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#promises that `return` requirement for promises

Comment: **Why** though? The `async`/`await` code is cleaner, simpler, shorter, and already working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify @jonrsharpe's comment you should return the promises from your test function:

```
test("total number of blogs", () => {
  return api.get('/api/blogs')
    .then( response => {
      expect(response.body).toHaveLength(1)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first version you return a Promise in the test. The testing library receives this promise and waits for it to finish before seeing the test as "finished".

So what you'll want to do is:

```js
test("total number of blogs", () => {
    return api.get('/api/blogs')
      .then( response => {
        expect(response.body).toHaveLength(1)
      })
  
})
```

Don't forget that the first example already works with promises (async/await is just promises)

Edited because I looked into the docs :p